# Exchange variable between two jFrames

Tags: java, netbeans

I have 3 java files. 
DBConn - This Class conencts to the database and execute query.

UserLogin - This jFrame will take username and password and compare with "users" table
            if it matches it will display "Login Successfull" in LibSysMain java file

LibSysMain - This is the main file which shows the menu. 
             This is the jFrame which is displayed first when application is run.

The problem is I am not able to set the "Login Successful" message in LibSysMain.

My Database is MS Access. Table name is "users". Field is "username" and "password". Both of them are of string type.

A help would be highly apprecited.

I am new in Java. I am using NetBeans 6.9.1.
Here is the list:

DBConn:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package LibSystem;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class DBConn {

    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;


    public void DoConnect(String querydb)
    {
        String SQL;
        SQL=querydb;

        try
        {
            // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Database\\libsys\\libsys.mdb";

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("\nConnected to the database");

            //QUERY THE DATABASE
            stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            //String SQL ="Select * from Members";
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            //MOVE CURSOR AT FIRST RECORD AND FETCH DATA
            rs.next();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
             System.out.println("\nClass not found. Check Path");
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException err)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

UserLogin:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * UserLogin.java
 *
 * Created on Apr 23, 2011, 8:46:59 PM
 */

package LibSystem;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.lang.*;


/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class UserLogin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private String user;
    private String password;
    private String status;

    /** Creates new form UserLogin */
    public UserLogin() {
        initComponents();
    }


    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        txtUserName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtPassword = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnClose = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnLogin = new javax.swing.JButton();
        lbUserName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lbPassword = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnClose.setText("Close");
        btnClose.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnCloseActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setText("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnLoginActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lbUserName.setText("User Name");

        lbPassword.setText("Password");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lbPassword)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(lbUserName)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(btnClose)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 64, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(btnLogin))
                            .addComponent(txtUserName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 180, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txtPassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 180, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addGap(35, 35, 35))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(lbUserName)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(txtUserName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(lbPassword)
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addComponent(txtPassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnClose)
                    .addComponent(btnLogin))
                .addContainerGap(39, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        //CREATE AN INSTANCE OF DBCONN CLASS TO CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
        //WE TAKE THE USERNAME FROM THE LOGIN WINDOW AND SEARCH THE USER
        //BASED ON THAT USER. IF FOUND, COMPARE IT WITH THE LOGIN WINDOW.
        //IF NOT FOUND DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE.

        DBConn dbc = new DBConn();
        String qry = "Select * from users where username=" + "'" + txtUserName.getText() + "'";
        dbc.DoConnect(qry);

        try
        {
            setUsername(dbc.rs.getString("username"));
            setPassword(dbc.rs.getString("password"));

            //TEST PRINTOUT OF USERNAME AND PASSWORD FOR DEBUGGING
            System.out.println(getUsername());
            System.out.println(getPassword());

           if (user.equals(txtUserName.getText()) && password.equals(txtPassword.getText()))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(UserLogin.this, "Login Successfull");
                this.setStatus("pass");
                dispose();
            }
            else
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(UserLogin.this, "Login unsuccessful");
               setStatus("fail");
            }


        }
        catch  (SQLException err)
        {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(UserLogin.this, err.getMessage());
        }

    }                                        

    private void btnCloseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
           this.dispose();
    }                                        

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new UserLogin().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setUsername(String u)
    {
        user = u;
    }

     public void setPassword(String p)
    {
        password = p;
    }


    public String getUsername()
    {
        return user;
    }

     public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

     public void setStatus(String stat)
    {
        status = stat;
    }

     public String getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnClose;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnLogin;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbPassword;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbUserName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtPassword;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtUserName;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

LibSysMain:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * LibsysMain.java
 *
 * Created on Apr 23, 2011, 6:48:18 PM
 */

package LibSystem;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class LibsysMain extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   String q;

    /** Creates new form LibsysMain */
    public LibsysMain()
    {
        initComponents();
        //DBConn dbc = new DBConn();
        //q="Select * from users";
        //dbc.DoConnect(q);
    }

//        LibsysMain frame1 = new LibsysMain();
//        UserLogin frame2 = new UserLogin(frame1);

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        miLogin = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowActivated(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 539, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 328, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jLabel1.setText("Status");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(518, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 25, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jSeparator1.setAlignmentX(0.0F);
        jSeparator1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(10, 10));

        miLogin.setText("Connect");
        miLogin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                miLoginActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jMenuItem1.setText("Login");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        miLogin.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuItem2.setText("Exit");
        jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        miLogin.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuBar1.add(miLogin);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 559, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(4, 4, 4)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void miLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                       

    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        UserLogin ul = new UserLogin();
        ul.setVisible(true);

        //SET THE STATUS IF LOGIN IS SUCCESSFULL
        if (ul.getStatus() == "pass")
        {
            jLabel1.setText("Logged In");
        }
        else
        {
            jLabel1.setText("Cannot Log in");
        }
    }                                          

    private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.exit(0);
    }                                          

    private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                    

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new LibsysMain().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu miLogin;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of suggestions:

- For one, don't compare Strings with == as you do here **if (ul.getStatus() == "pass")** as this checks to see if two variables refer to the same String object (which you don't care about) but rather use either the equals or the equalsIgnoreCase method which checks to see if the two Strings contain the same String data (which you do care about). e.g., **if (ul.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("pass"))**
- Be sure to do all of your database queries and whatnot in a thread background to the GUI's thread, the EDT such as can be achieved by using a SwingWorker object. This article will tell you what I said but will give you the details: [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).
- Consider using a single JFrame and modal dialogs to act as dialog windows to the main app. This can be achieved by using JOptionPanes or modal JDialogs, in particular for your UserLogin window.
- For this reason, I like to gear my GUI's towards creating JPanels rather than top level windows such as JFrames.  This way I can place my GUI/JPanel into any type of window I desire depending on the situation be it a JFrame, a JApplet, a JDialog, a JOptionPane, or even nested into another JPanel. This gives you an amazing amount of flexibilty.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I will try on what you said and revert. It might take some time as I am a fresher in this technology and NetBeans is a total new world for me.

Comment: @Shahid: You're welcome. Please come back and ask further questions if you don't understand points. If you do this and especially if you need to post code, edit your original question to show the new information and questions, and then place a comment notifying us of the changes.  Luck!